# Customized counter ordered list alignment issue

Tags: css, html-lists, text-align

I have a simple ordered list. I used counter-reset property to change the styles for number. But the issue is when the container (`.list`) width is small the list doesn't align directly like an ordered list should do.

```css
.list{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ol{
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: csscounter;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

li{
    counter-increment:csscounter;
    margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}
li:before{
  content: counter(csscounter);
  background: gray;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='list'>
<ol>
  <li>
    Enter your mobile number to view  your book collection
  </li>
  <li>
    Select the books that you want to add to your collection
  </li>
  <li>
    Confirm and Submit
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

If I remove the css properties for `<ol>` the list renders correctly and no alignment issues occurs.

```css
.list{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='list'>
<ol>
  <li>
    Enter your mobile number to view  your book collection
  </li>
  <li>
    Select the books that you want to add to your collection
  </li>
  <li>
    Confirm and Submit
  </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<ul>` has different paddings.

[image]

The problem is that you introduced a ::before pseudo element. You have to rework your paddings and margins.

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: csscounter;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  counter-increment: csscounter;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(csscounter);
  background: gray;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-left: -1.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ol>
    <li>
      Enter your mobile number to view your book collection
    </li>
    <li>
      Select the books that you want to add to your collection
    </li>
    <li>
      Confirm and Submit
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a thought: if you would set `width: 2rem` and `margin-left: 2rem` for `li::before` (same as `padding-left: 2rem` of the `ol`, wouldn’t you get a better centered item instead of trying to pseudo-center using `width: 1.5rem` and `margin-left: -1.75rem` to pull it to the left?

Comment: The "problem" (which is not actually a problem) is that you are using a pseudo element. Browsers understand that element the same way you have your characters. The negative margin actually pushes the whole line to the right. Here have a look - [link](https://css-tricks.com/custom-list-number-styling/)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to avoid a duplicate answer**.

You can also use ,[`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker),  `padding`, [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) and a [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) background:

possible example

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
::marker{color:#ddd;}
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-indent: -1.5em;
  padding: 0.3em 0 0.2em 2em;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle at 0.8em 0.9em,
    gray 0.6em,
    tomato,
    transparent 0.75em
  );
}
```

```html
<div class='list'>
<ol>
  <li>
    Enter your mobile number to view  your book collection
  </li>
  <li>
    Select the books that you want to add to your collection
  </li>
  <li>
    Confirm and Submit
  </li> 
</ol>
</div>
```